# Calendar in PHP language

Tags: php, calendar

i got a calendar in php and i just wanna know two simple things!

How to make the calendar start in a day that isn't sunday ? (Like, day 1 = monday, for example).

And how to make all sundays appears in red ?

Thx and here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calendário em PHP</title>
    <?php 
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Estamos em <?php echo date('Y');?></h1>
        <p>Hoje é dia <strong><?php echo date('d / '); ?></strong>
            <?php echo date('m'); ?>
            agora são <?php echo date ('H'); ?>horas e
            <?php echo date('i');?> minutos.</p>

        <?php
            function linha($semana){
                echo "<tr>";
                for ($i = 0; $i <=6; $i++){
                    if(isset($semana[$i])){
                        echo "<td>{$semana[$i]}</td>";
                    } else{
                        echo "<td></td>";
                    }
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            function calendario(){
                $dia = 1;
                $semana = array();

                while($dia <= 31){
                    array_push($semana, $dia);
                    if(count($semana) == 7){
                        linha($semana);
                        $semana = array();
                    }
                    $dia++;
                }
                linha($semana);
            }
        ?>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Dom</th>
                <th>Seg</th>
                <th>Ter</th>
                <th>Qua</th>
                <th>Qui</th>
                <th>Sex</th>
                <th>Sáb</th>
                <?php calendario(); ?>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calendário em PHP</title>
    <?php 
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

        $hoje = getdate();

        $ultimoDia = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,
                                       $hoje['mon'],
                                       $hoje['year']);

        $primeiraSemana = (($hoje['wday'] + 1) -
                          ($hoje['mday'] - ((int)($hoje['mday'] / 6) * 7))) % 7;
        // Alternativa:
        /*$primeiroDiaTimestamp = strtotime(sprintf("%d-%0d-01",
                                                  $hoje['year'],
                                                  $hoje['mon']));
        $primeiraSemana = (int)date('w', $primeiroDiaTimestamp);*/
    ?>

    <style>
        td[data-semana="0"] { color: #ff0000; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Estamos em <?= $hoje['year'] ?></h1>
    <p><?= sprintf('Hoje é dia <strong>%0d / %0d</strong>, agora são %02d horas e %0d minutos.',
                   $hoje['mday'], $hoje['mon'], $hoje['hours'], $hoje['minutes'])
    ?></p>

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Dom</th>
            <th>Seg</th>
            <th>Ter</th>
            <th>Qua</th>
            <th>Qui</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>Sáb</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <?php
        for($semana = 0; $semana < $primeiraSemana; ++$semana) {
            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
        for($dia = 1; $dia < $ultimoDia; ++$dia) {
            if( $semana > 6 ) {
                $semana = 0;
                echo '</tr><tr>';
            }

            echo "<td data-semana=\"$semana\">";
            echo "$dia</td>";
            ++$semana;
        }
        for(; $semana < 7; ++$semana) {
            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
        ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Using strtotime and date you can get the week day of the first day of the month like this:

```
$firstWeekdayOfTheMonth = date('w', strtotime('first day of this month'));
```

The solution that I present uses an arithmetic calculation to find what's the first weekday of the month, knowing the current month and week days:

```
$today = getdate();
$firstWeekdayOfTheMonth = (($today['wday'] + 1) - ($today['mday'] - ((int)($today['mday'] / 6) * 7))) % 7;
```

It counts the days of the full weeks (7 days) passed this month: for instance, today is the 11th day of the month, thus this one full week (11 / 6 = 1.6...) has passed. A week has 7 days.

Next, it calculates the difference between the days passed this month and the days counted previously. 11 - 7 = 4. If the first day of the month falls on Sunday, today would be Thursday (7 days since Monday plus 4 days). It is required to shift the correct days (using a number of the current week day) in order to have the correct week day: 7 - 4 = 3 (it's a seven, because it's the 7th day since Sunday; 3 represents a Wednesday).

Answer (score 0):

The function date() offers a lot to compare the day of the week. Obviously, you need to tell PHP what the day of reference is, so that PHP knows what days it is.

In your example, you can set a timestamp of reference, and use date('N', $current_timestamp):

- You can compare against the day of the week in your loop (1 = Monday to 7 = Sunday) to make you calendar start only the day you want.
- You can check if == to 7 (Sunday)
- You can check if it is the day of today
- Etc.

I rewrote the calendar function using this function :

```
    <?php

$calendar = "";
$current_time = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n"), 1) - 604800; // say, we start at the first day of the current month.


$days = "";


    for ($w = 1 ; $w <=5 ; $w++) // how many weeks to display.
    {
        $week = "";
        $days = "";

        for ($j = 1 ; $j <=7 ; $j++) // for each day slot in your week
        {

            if($j != date('N', $current_time)) 
            {
                $days .= "";    // if the current looped day is not corresponding to the day in the calendar column, then empty slot and we don't increment the day until it matches.
                $j=$j-1;
            }
            else if(date('Ymd') == date('Ymd', $current_time))
            {
                $days .= "<td style=\"background-color:yellow;\">" . date('j', $current_time) . "</td>\n"; // if the day is today, then print in the calendar in yellow.
            }
            else if ($j == 7)
            {
                $days .= "<td style=\"background-color:red;\">" . date('j', $current_time) . "</td>\n"; // if Sunday, then in red.
            }
            else
            {
                $days .= "<td>" . date('j', $current_time) . "</td>\n"; // if the day corresponds but is not today, then print in the calendar (white).
            }

            $current_time = $current_time + 86400;
        }

        $week .= "<tr>" . $days . "</tr>\n";

        $calendar .=  $week;
    }


echo ("<table cellspacing=\"2\" border=\"1\">
\t<tr>
\t<th>M</th>
\t<th>T</th>
\t<th>W</th>
\t<th>T</th>
\t<th>F</th>
\t<th>S</th>
\t<th>S</th>
</tr>" . $calendar . "</table>");

?>
```